# PPPD over serial, good iperf results, poor real (scp/streaming) bitrate

Tags: networking, serial-port

My goal is to have TCP/IP capable connection between two devices which are connected with each other using radio transceivers connected to each device using serial port. Their maximum bitrate is in theory 500kbps. I have managed to establish such connection using pppd:

`pppd crtscts noauth lock 172.100.0.1:172.100.0.2 /dev/ttyUSB0 460800`

It works fine, I can ssh from one to another. I have run iperf3 (server: `iperf3 -s`, client: `iperf3 -c 172.100.0.1`). The result was:

```
Connecting to host 172.100.0.1, port 5201
[  4] local 172.100.0.2 port 33740 connected to 172.100.0.1 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  56.2 KBytes   460 Kbits/sec    0   12.4 KBytes
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  70.4 KBytes   577 Kbits/sec    0   15.8 KBytes
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   129 KBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec    0   21.5 KBytes
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  78.8 KBytes   645 Kbits/sec    0   25.0 KBytes
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  90.3 KBytes   739 Kbits/sec    0   29.2 KBytes
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   113 KBytes   931 Kbits/sec    0   34.3 KBytes
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  21.2 KBytes   174 Kbits/sec    0   34.5 KBytes
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  39.2 KBytes   321 Kbits/sec    0   34.5 KBytes
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  54.9 KBytes   450 Kbits/sec    0   34.5 KBytes
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  29.6 KBytes   243 Kbits/sec    0   34.5 KBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   683 KBytes   559 Kbits/sec    0             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   621 KBytes   509 Kbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

bidirectional tests with `-d` gave similar results.

However, when I try to scp a file (generated using `dd if=/dev/urandom of=~/randfile bs=1M count=1` I get very repeatable results of ~20-25 KB/s (lower the mpu, lower the transfer), over 2 times worse then iperf3:

```
scp ~/randfile user@ip:/path
100% 1024KB  20.3KB/s   00:50
```

Do you have any idea what can be causing such difference? I tried video streaming and results were roughly the same, I achieved 150kbps with UDP, I could not get 200kbps working. I will give SLIP a try which should have lower overhead then pppd.

EDIT

result of pppstats
device1:

```
pppstats -r -v
      IN   PACK VJCOMP VJTOSS NON-VJ  RATIO  UBYTE  |      OUT   PACK VJCOMP VJSRCH VJMISS  RATIO  UBYTE
 1980812  17773   9606      0    968   1.15 1595821  |  6156633  34099  18485    480     13   3.69 5387948
```

device2:

```
pppstats -r -v
      IN   PACK VJCOMP VJTOSS NON-VJ  RATIO  UBYTE  |      OUT   PACK VJCOMP VJSRCH VJMISS  RATIO  UBYTE
 6155869  34092  18485      0   7687   3.69 5387156  |  1979984  17762   9606    422     14   1.15 1594949
```

Comment: I note there is a `pppstats` command. It might give some insight.

Comment: I have attached stats.